# Change target API on published application

Tags: android

I would like to change the target API (in order to make it posible to install my app on the sdcard). I know how to change the API (Right click on project --> properties...) and I am able to compile and export with `android:installLocation="auto`" and install on my phone works fine. But when trying to update an already installed version the installation fails.

Do I need to change something else or is it even possible to change the target API on a published application?

Comment: "the installation fails" is not enough. What error message does it give?

Answer (score 2):

You need to publish update to your app on market. In order to do that you need to change versionCode and versionNumber values and sigh new apk using the same keystore.